# RunTime Error when using requests_html with python

Tags: python, python-requests-html

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
def scrape_prices():
    session = HTMLSession()
    url = 'https://opensea.io/collection/wonderpals? 
        search[sortBy]=PRICE&search[sortAscending]=true&search[toggles]. 
        [0]=BUY_NOW'
    r = session.get(url)
    r.html.render(sleep=1, keep_page=True, scrolldown=100)
    substring = "<div class=" + '"' + "AssetCardFooter--name" + '"'
    item_numbers = r.html.find(substring)
```

I have installed: pip3 install requests-html. I continue to get the following error: RuntimeError:

> File
> "/Users/ethanwells/Library/MobileDocuments/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/All-Things-Code/Python/opensea2/metadataScraper2/prices.py",
> line 12, in scrape_prices r.html.render(sleep=1,
> keep_page=True,scrolldown=100)
>
> File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests_html.py",
> line 586, in render self.browser = self.session.browser  #
> Automatically create a event loop and browser
>
> File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests_html.py",
> line 727, in browser self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
>
> File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py",
> line 656, in get_event_loop raise RuntimeError('There is no current
> event loop in thread %r.'
>
> RuntimeError: There is no current event loop
> in thread 'MainThread'.

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: Please see this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53180478/runtimeerror-there-is-no-current-event-loop-in-thread-thread-1-requests-ht

Comment: I'm not sure how I could implement the solution from the thread you suggested to work with my implementation.